# how to find maximum of values obtained in each iteration to append it to a list

Tags: python, list, loops

Given a number `n`, write a program to find the sum of the largest prime factors of each of nine consecutive numbers starting from `n`.

I am able to get the factors but for each value if there are multiple factors which are prime I want only the maximum values among the those prime factors which I can't get.

```
def find_g(num):
    factor=[]
    list1=[]
    list2=[]
    for i in range(0,num-1):
        factor.append(num+i)
    print(factor)
    for f in factor:
        for i in range(2,f+1):
            if(f%i==0 and i%2!=0):
                list1.append(i)
                print(list1)
                list2.append(max(list1))
        list1=[]

    print(list2)

print(find_g(10))
```

Input: `10`
Desired Output: `[5, 11, 3, 13, 7, 5, 17, 9]`
Actual Output: `[5, 11, 3, 13, 7, 3, 5, 15, 17, 3, 9]`

Comment: I don't understand the task. What is "sum of the largest prime factors"? There is only one _largest_ prime factor...

Comment: For example,
g(10)=f(10)+f(11)+f(12)+f(13)+f(14)+f(15)+f(16)+f(17)+f(18) 
        =5 + 11 + 3 + 13 + 7 + 5 + 2 + 17 + 3 
        =66

Comment: the largest prime factor for 10 is 5(among its factors 2,5,10 only 2 and 5 are primes and among 2 and 5 largest prime is 5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can break this down into two parts: (A) find the largest prime factor for any given number `n`, and (B) sum the largest prime factors of each of nine consecutive numbers starting from `n`. I'll describe code for each, and then combine them.

(A) We can find the largest prime factor for a number `n`, `lpf(n)`, with the below code:

```
def lpf(n):
    i = 2
    while i * i <= n:
        if n % i:
            i += 1
        else:
            n //= i
    return n
```

(B) Then, we can run this code for each number from `n` to `n+9` by mapping the `lpf` function across `range(n, n+9)` and summing the result:

```
def find_g(n):
    return sum(map(lpf, range(n, n+9)))
```

For your case of `n=10`, we get

```
find_g(10) = 66
```

This is correct because the largest prime factors for [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19] are, respectively, [5, 11, 3, 13, 7, 5, 2, 17, 3].

(Note that your expected answer is incorrect, can you figure out why?)